# IPSec Phase 2 Configuration For Translated Subnets?

Tags: networking, vpn, ipsec, pfsense, tunnel

I have two networks with the `10.0.0.0/8` subnet I'm trying to connect via IPSec tunnels.  I have the phase 1 configurations working but am a bit stuck on the phase 2 configurations.  Each firewall used is running pfSense.  There are two primary cases I'd like to configure these for:

**Case 1:**
A `/32` virtual NAT address exposing a network to another network.

`Network A`:
Firewall 0: `10.1.1.1/8`
Subnet to NAT: `10.9.9.0/24`

`Network B`:
Firewall 1: `10.1.1.1/8` (passthrough to `Firewall 2`)
Firewall 2: `10.27.1.1/16` (manages `Network B` IPSec tunnel)
Exposed NAT address on `Network B`: `10.27.254.9/32`

Such that `Network A` is exposed to `Network B` more or less like plugging a firewall into the WAN address `10.27.254.9/32` containing the LAN subnet `10.9.9.0/24` with NAT rules managed by `Firewall 0`.

**Case 2:**
A `/24` subnet to access two networks each way in the following manner.

`Network A`:
Firewall 0: `10.1.1.1/8`
Subnet to Translate: `10.31.1.0/24`
Translation on `Network B`: `10.254.31.0/24`

`Network B`:
Firewall 1: `10.1.1.1/8` (passthrough to `Firewall 2`)
Firewall 2: `10.58.1.1/16` (manages `Network B` IPSec tunnel)
Subnet to Translate: `10.58.1.0/24`
Translation on `Network A`: `10.254.58.0/24`

Such that from `Network A` I could ping `10.254.58.72` and reach `10.58.1.72` on `Network B` and similarly ping `10.254.31.81` from `Network B` and reach `10.31.1.81` on `Network A`.  If this isn't possible due to the `/16` limitation on `Firewall 2` I could move the IPSec phase 1 and phase 2 configurations for this one to `Firewall 1` (though the preference would be to have the `10.254.31.0/24` translated subnet be visible only from within the `10.58.0.0/16` subnet on `Network B`.

Any help would be appreciated, I've been racking my brain against these phase 2 IPSec configurations for some time now.

Comment: Don't use NAT, if possible (and it most likely is possible).

Comment: @MichaelHampton the two use cases vary based on different network configurations.